# Is it possible to copy and paste code containing variables from one override to another in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, overriding, joomla3.2

I want to adapt my tags result page (default_items.php) so that instead of only showing the articles title it also shows the core article introduction as shown on a category blog page (blog.php).

I thought I'd do this using overrides by copying the code that outputs the article introduction (round about line 82)

```
<?php
   $this->item = &$item;
   echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
?>
```

into the default_items.php file.

All I get is the following error 500 - Layout default_item not found.

Does anyone know how to do this/what the problem is with my approach? Do I just need to define the variables in the default_items.php?

I'm using Joomla 3.2

Comment: Yes you can copy the code but you need to make sure the variables have the same names.

Comment: For doing what you want you will want to use `$item->body` since that is the common name that all tagged items are standardized to use.

Comment: @Elin Not sure what exactly you meant, I tried the following: `<?php $this->item->body = &$item; echo $this->body->loadTemplate('item'); ?>` On the front end only the link to the first article is displayed, there is no description and the template is gone. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have the &? Also sorry I meant core_body.

Comment: @Elin Right, I took the & out and added core_: `<?php $this->item->core_body = $item; echo $this->core_body->loadTemplate('item'); ?>` There is still no difference.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know why you would be loading a template as part of echoing core_body??

Comment: Also by the way if you don't use the compact list layout there is just a menu option to show the text.

Comment: I just want to show the article description below the articles title, (within my template). I don't know if I need to echo core_body for that? You mean there is a menu option in components->tags->options for this? All I found was and option to show tag descriptions.

Comment: Yes there is a menu option for it .. he way tags work is that since it allows lists that combine many different content types it has to standardize the field references. So the introtext in articles and the description in weblinks (as two examples) are both mapped to core_body.

Comment: Where can I find the menu option? I suppose it should be in components->tags->options, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have overridden the tag view ( /components/com_tags/views/tag/tmpl/ ). You are in the default_item.php - file in this override, and from here you are calling

```
<?php
   $this->item = &$item;
   echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
?>
```

What Joomla does now is to try to load i file default_item_item.php. Since this file does not exist on the path, (the path includes /components/com_tags/views/tag/tmpl, and your override /templates/yourtemplate/html/com_tags/tag ) a 500-error is thrown.

What you should do is to se what data is loaded in the items. Try

```
<?php
print_r($this->item); 
?>
```

This will show whatever data is available in the current view (you could also try print_r($this) to see if there are other interesting variables in the current view object that you would like to use. )

If the data you need ( the introtext? ) is not available in $this->item, then there are a couple of solutions to load more data:

- Load the data directly in the view. This is quick and dirty, but contradicts the mvc-model.
- Write a content-plugin and load the data in the onContentPrepare - function. This function is called in /component/com_tags/views/tag/view.html.php

The procedure to load the data is similar in both occations. Tell me if you need more help with it...

regards Jonas

Comment: I think the introtext is available in $this->item, this is what is displayed after the readmore: `stdClass Object ( [id] => 48 [title] => mytitle [alias] => myalias [introtext] =>` After that the full article is displayed. Is `[introtext]`the variable I am looking for? And how do I load it into the default_items.php?

Comment: Yes, well, you basically need to print the introtext whereever you want to show it, like this: <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>. You can wrap it in a div-tag to encapulate it from the rest of the code.

Comment: I added the code you suggested into the default_items.php on line 83 wrapped in p tags. I see no difference on the front end. Is it possible that I still need something else?

Comment: Hmm, thats strange. You should not wrap in p-tags, as the introtext probably already has paragraphs. But you should see something anyway ...

Comment: try this: echo "INTROTEXT";  echo $this->item->introtext; echo "INTROTEXT_END"; die();

Comment: Found the mistake with the override, I was editting the wrong file. `echo $this->item->introtext; ?>` does not change anything, `echo $this->item->introtext; die();` only shows a link to the first article as an ul, all the other articles with the same tag do not appear. And finally `echo "INTROTEXT"; echo $this->item->introtext; echo "INTROTEXT_END"; die();` shows the same just with `INTROTEXTINTROTEXT_END` written below it. Every time I used the `die();` the whole template disappeared.

Comment: If you are in tags it is not called introtext.

Comment: `echo this->item->core_body`